# Vanishing sums of roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, cyclic-groups, roots-of-unity

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. The nonempty subset $P \subseteq \{0,1,\cdots,N-1\}$ satisfies 
$$ \sum_{k \in P} e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{N}}=0. $$

**Example:**

If $N$ is prime, then the only possibility is that $P=\{0,1,\cdots,N-1\}$.

If $N=pq$, then the set $P$ can be $\{0,q,2q,\cdots,(p-1)q\}$.

If $N=2m$, then the set $P$ can be $\{j,m+j\}$ for $0\le j<m$.

---

**Question**: can we describe all possibilities of the set $P$?

Comment: A trivial reduction: you only need to find the $P$ which contain $0$, as  $P$ satisfies condition iff $\zeta P$ does ($\zeta the primitive root of unity.).

Comment: And I have a sort of recollection that in looking at a similar problem one didn't see the general picture until one looked at examples like $N=3003$. Factorise $X^{3003}-1$ to see what I  mean.